# Excel, how to get cell value from another workbook, using cell value as a reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

need help please, I need to get cell value from another workbook, without opening it, cause there are so many workbook i need to work with

Lets say I work in book1.xlsx, and the cell value I need to link with is in workbook A.xlsx, B.xlsx, etc

I have the list of the workbook I need to open, and the cell I need in workbook A,B,etc is in the same sheet, lets say Sheet1, cell A1 in each workbook

In book1.xlsx I listed the workbook in :
A1= A.xlsx
A2= B.xlsx

The sheet in B1= Sheet1
Cell in C1 = $A$1

I succesfully get the value using indirect by using 
=INDIRECT("'[" & A1 & "]" & B1 & "'!" & C1)

but the problem with indirect is I need to open the workbook >< (about few hundreds workbook)

Tried with Index with the same approach, but I'm stuck

Index looks like can succesfully open when the file is closed using
=INDEX([A.xlsx]Sheet1!A:A,1,1)
but not working with =INDEX('D:["&A1&"]Sheet1'!A:A,1,1) 
all the files are in D:\ directory

Any solution / suggestion ? thx in advance

Comment: `I need to get cell value from another workbook, without opening it,` That's what this does. Clarify and edit your question or add a comment here if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a relative link:

Say bookB.xlsx has a value you want in cell A1.

='[bookB.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1